# Ubuntu and XFCE: unmute sound

Tags: linux, audio, xfce, alsa, mute

I've installed XFCE for Ubuntu and use it as my default X session. 
After this change some sound problems appeared:

I can mute sound with alsamixer or with hotkey on a keyboard.
But just reenable it isn't enough to unmute sound.

In order to unmute it I need to:

- go to alsamixer:
- Mute master, headphone and speaker
- Unmute one by one master headphone and speaker quickly and in this exact order

This is the only way I can make it work again.

The problem didn't appear when I use handphones.

How can it be?

Answer (score 5):

The bug is not in Ubuntu, it is in Xfce. There is a temporary fix. Open a terminal and write:

```
pactl set-sink-mute 1 0
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: I think this bug arises because of using both `alsa and pulseausio`. I believe when we press `mute key` it mutes both alsa and pulse but when try to unmute it unmutes alsa only. Therefore no sound. What your command does is it unmutes pulse-audio so sound is back to normal.

Comment: @RanRag Thanks for that hint. This did work for me as well.

Comment: Ridiculous bug. I've created an additional sound icon for this command. Any links to the bug?

Answer (score 1):

In graphical xfce settings editor >  xfce-mixer > active-card, give your active card name.

**Finding your active card**

Open audio mixer for Xfce.It has drop down list of sound cards. Try and see which one is controlling Volume. Name of the card you have selected in audio mixer will appear as 'sound card' under 'xfce-mixer' in graphical xfce settings editor. Copy the 'sound card' name and paste it in 'active card' name.

Comment: This can also be done via a command line via `xfconf-query -c xfce4-mixer -p /sound-card -s PlaybackBuiltinAudioAnalogStereoPulseAudioMixer` (sound card name might differ)